# Django unable to redirect when link is clicked

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates

In my template I have the following:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for category in categories %}
        {% url 'post' category as url %}
        <a href="{{ url }}">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="" alt="Avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4><b>{{ category }}</b></h4> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
{%  endblock %}
```

The page renders fine when I run the local development server, however when I click on any of the links, nothing happens.

Here is my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^all/', views.all_jobs, name="all"),
    url(r'^post/', views.pick_category, name="post_category"),
    url(r'^post/(?P<category>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.post_job, name="post"),
    url(r'^job/(?P<job_pk>\d+)/$', views.get_job, name="get_job"),
]
```

Why is this not working?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I have changed the view code to the following and now the correct url appears but still the view function is not called:

```
<a href="{% url 'jobs:post' category %}">
```

My view looks like this:

```
def post_job(request, category):
    form = find_type_of_form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = find_type_of_form(category, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            job = form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "Job successfully posted!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(job.get_absolute_url())

    return render(request, 'jobs/post_job_form.html', {'form': form})

def find_type_of_form(category, request_type=None):
    if category == categories[0]:
        return forms.BabysittingForm(request_type)
    elif category == categories[1]:
        return forms.TutoringForm(request_type)
    elif category == categories[2]:
        return forms.PetsittingForm(request_type)
    elif category == categories[3]:
        return forms.ShoppingForm(request_type)
```

Comment: Have you checked what is in rendered HTML? Can you pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't terminated your pick_category URL pattern, so it matches everything *beginning with* "post/". . Make sure you use a trailing dollar sign:

```
url(r'^post/$', views.pick_category, name="post_category"),
```

Comment: Thanks dude you saved me a headache!

Answer (score 0):

I think you has a problem in this code `{% url 'post' category as url %}`,  I suggest you to change with this;

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% url 'post' category=category.slug %} {# an example using slug field #}
    <a href="{{ url }}">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="" alt="Avatar">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>{{ category }}</b></h4> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

> **As a note**, don't use object as the url.